# angular2-sails 404 error (not found)

Tags: sql-server, angular, sails.js

I am having difficulty hooking up my sql server with a front end of angular 2.

I ran the sailsjs getting started guide

I then hooked up angular2 with sails. I followed the sharpten guide
http://sharpten.com/blog/2016/02/02/integrating-angular-2-with-sails-js.html

I then used the sails-sqlserver package to connect to my localhost sql server
sails-sqlserver

I have the sails returning my data and now i want to use angular 2 to interact with the data.

I found the angular2-sails package.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-sails

However, I am getting a 404 error with the angular2-sails package

ERROR:
zone.js:1382 
"GET http: //localhost:1337/node_modules/angular2-sails/ 404 (Not Found)"

How do i get rid of this 404 error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work with version 0.1.4 of angular2-sails. 
i commented out the sailsmodule due to version 0.1.4 just having the SailsService
//import {SailsModule} from "angular2-sails";

In my component I imported the SailsService
import {SailsService} from "angular2-sails/dist/index";